# Can native Android apps be built without the SDK?

Tags: android, sdk

Can native Android apps be built without the Android SDK?

The Android SDK license agreement section 3.2 forbids me to use it to "develop another SDK". My goal is explicitly to make an app that is itself an SDK for making games on Android.

I'm taking about native Android apps in particular. I believe hybrid apps still require a native app wrapper to be built and hence run into the same question, and have lower performance than SDK/NDK. Progressive web apps will not have the performance or device locality I seek.

I'm talking about the Android SDK, not the Android Studio IDE. "Use Eclipse" or "Run it from the command line." would be mistaken advice if it still relies on the SDK.

Comment: I wonder if you could build your SDK library, then delete any Android SDK bundled libraries, that get compiled into the build.  Then, anyone who includes your library in their project have to also include the Android SDK library into their project?

Comment: @Michael Dougan The idea is to create an Android app which itself serves as an IDE/runtime with integrated interpreter and debugger, not a library for people to include in their conventional project.